# How to identify combined redundancy in independent variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with about 15 independent variables for linear regression.  One variable has strong correlation with the dependent variable when tested by itself.  A correlation matrix also shows that it does not perfectly (or even very closely) correlate with any other independent variable.  However, when I create a linear model with all of the variables, this variable turns out to add no predictive power.  I assume this means it is redundant with some combination of other variables in the model.  Aside from manually checking every combination of independent variables myself which include that variable, is there some automated way to determine *which* other variables collectively render this one redundant?

Comment: It seems the immediate solution would be to regress the new variable against the other predictors?

Comment: That's interesting.  If I did an exhaustive test of the other predictors on the assumed-redundant variable, I think this would identify the fewest needed to predict it fully, if indeed there is some combination of the other variables that would predict if fully.  I will try.  Thanks!